# How to enable vibration on scan in scanner page when the vibrate checklist tile is true on setting page in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

```
class ScannerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(bool) onBeepSettingChanged;
  final bool beepChecked;

   const ScannerPage({Key? key,  required this.onBeepSettingChanged, required this.beepChecked,}) : super(key: key);
   @override
  State<ScannerPage> createState() => _ScannerPageState();
}

class _ScannerPageState extends State<ScannerPage> {
  List<String> selectedImages = [];
  String scanResult = "";
  // bool scannerVibrateEnabled = false;

  Future<void> _vibrate() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool scannervibrationEnabled = prefs.getBool('vibrationEnabled') ?? true;

    if (scannervibrationEnabled ) {
      Vibration.vibrate(duration: 500);
    }
  }
  Future<void> scanQR() async {

    try {
      final scanResult = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
        '#ff6666',
        'Cancel',
        true,
        ScanMode.BARCODE,

      );

      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(() {
        this.scanResult = scanResult;
      });
    log('de_alam scanner $scanResult');

    if(scanResult=="-1"){
      return;
    }

      if (scanResult.isNotEmpty) {
        Navigator.push(this.context ,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => ResultPage(scanResult: scanResult ),
          ),
        );
        // widget.onBeepSettingChanged(widget.beepChecked);
      }
    } on PlatformException {
      setState(() {
        this.scanResult = "Failed to get platform version";
        });
    }
  }
```

I have an app, in which I have a **setting_page** in it .I want to add vibration in it  also I want when I click on vibration button it will main true and then when I open **scanpage** this vibrate sound produce on scan. When i checked true of vibration_button in **setting_page** it will produce vibration on scan in **scanner_page**.I am using **CheckListTile** in **setting_page** .please help me to do this .

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge and understanding, this is what you've been looking for. It's a QR code scanner with vibration functionality. In the below-written code, the vibrator will only vibrate if the `vibrationEnabled` value is `true` & QR code is scanned `successfully` & has a `valid` value.

```
import "dart:async";
import "dart:developer";

import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:flutter_barcode_scanner/flutter_barcode_scanner.dart";
import "package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart";
import "package:vibration/vibration.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(title: "My App", home: HomePage());
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    unawaited(scanQR());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: scanQR, child: const Text("scanQR")),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> scanQR() async {
    final String result = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
      "#ff6666",
      "Cancel",
      true,
      ScanMode.BARCODE,
    );
    log("scanResult: $result");
    if (result.isEmpty) {
      // Write something if result.isEmpty...
    } else if (result == "-1") {
      // Write something if result == "-1"...
    } else if (result.isNotEmpty) {
      await vibrate();
      if (mounted) {
        // Write something if result.isNotEmpty. Your navigation code goes here.
      } else {
        return;
      }
    } else {
      // Write something if result is unknown / undetermined...
    }
    return Future<void>.value();
  }

  Future<void> vibrate() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    (prefs.getBool("vibrationEnabled") ?? true)
        ? await Vibration.vibrate()
        : log("Vibration is disabled");
    return Future<void>.value();
  }
}
```

Comment: as other setting page when we allow setting or make the checklist as tick then that functionality perform on the app right. So now i have lists of setting in my setting page because i am making an app which is Scanner app ,in the app settings are "vibrate on scan " ,"beep sound on scan complete " when the user marked as true of vibrate and beep sound

Comment: i hope you understand my instructions

Comment: I don't understand. What is beepChecked & What is onBeepSettingChanged? What's the purpose of these? Explain a bit more.

Comment: actually i want to add vibration initially

Comment: please check my statement i hope you understand

Comment: You can call the vibrate() method whenever & whenever you like.

Comment: Open QR Scanner first then vibrate:
unawaited(scanQR());
unawaited(vibrate());

Vibrate first then open QR Scanner:
unawaited(vibrate());
unawaited(scanQR());

Comment: from where i can add?